# cypress retrieve JWToken and set as header for further requests

Tags: node.js, express, cypress

When trying to test a express webapplication i build the test should first authenticate to retrieve a JWT token, the token retrieving works but the method to set the header for further requests doesn't work.

This code creates the method to run when authentication is needed,

```
Cypress.Commands.add("userRequest", function(requestObj) {

    // Make a login request, returning a JWT token
    cy.request({
        method: 'POST', 
        url: '/credentials',
        body: {
            "name": "test_user",
            "password": "test123_"
        }
    }).then(function(response) {
        requestObj.headers = requestObj.headers || {};
        requestObj.headers.Authentication = response.body.token;

        return cy.request(requestObj);
    });
```

This is the code that runs

```
it('retrieves one user', function () {
        cy.userRequest(cy.request({
            url: '/users/1'
        })).then(function (response) {
            expect(response.body.name).to.equal("admin");
        });
    });
```

BUT when the test runs the console tells me

> CypressError: cy.request() failed on:
>
> http://localhost:3000/users/1
>
> The response we received from your web server was:
>
> 401: Unauthorized
>
> This was considered a failure because the status code was not '2xx' or '3xx'.

Can anyone help me?

thanks in advance!

Comment: cypress works on async programming, you can't have cy.userRequest(cy.request()), it is not designed to work in this way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in my comment that cypress works on async programming, so try with in support/command.js

```
Cypress.Commands.add('userRequest', (email, password) => {
Cypress.log({
  name: 'loginViaAuth0',
});
    const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/credentials',   
   "body":'userName='+email+'&Password='+password+'
  };
  cy.request(options)

});
```

Then in your code

```
cy.userRequest(userName,password)
  .its('body').then((response)=>{

  // Do your stuffs

 })
```